# Lookup for specific text in cell and VLOOKUP if it contains

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have range with IATA codes in $B$2:$B$3591 and destination names with IATA codes in $A$2:$A$3591. I would like to search for IATA code based on values in range $A$2:$A$3591. The problem is that I can't use exact match as exact text can't be entered.

For example if I type **Bromma**, formula should display **BMA**. If I type **Arlanda**, formula should display **ARN** and etc.

```
         A                                  B
Stavropol, Russia (STW)                    STW
Stavanger, Norway (SVG)                    SVG
Stella Maris, Bahamas (SML)                SML
Stockholm, Sweden - All airports (STO)     STO
Stockholm, Sweden - Arlanda (ARN)          ARN
Stockholm, Sweden - Bromma (BMA)           BMA
Stornoway, United Kingdom (SYY)            SYY
Storuman, Sweden (SQO)                     SQO
Strasbourg, France - Bus service (XER)     XER
Strasbourg, France - Entzheim (SXB)        SXB
Stronsay, United Kingdom (SOY)             SOY
Stung Treng, Cambodia (TNX)                TNX
```

I have tried `=VLOOKUP(E3&"*";$A$2:$B$3591;2;FALSE)` so that in E3 I type Bromma but it does not work. However this works for Stavropol for example.

Comment: instead of `E3&"*"` use `"*"&E3&"*"` to search for it anywhere not just the beginning

Comment: @ScottCraner you can add your comment as an asewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `E3$"*"`

Will only match the begining of the the text.  Add another wild card for the start:

```
"*"&E3&"*"
```

To Match on text anywhere in the string.